# UFT- Can I get the result of an action during run?

Tags: testing, vbscript, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I have created a test with 1 action which contains n actions. Is there any way to check after the execution of each action of the n actions the result if it is fail or pass and proceed accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

the solution is to use "`Reporter.CurrentActionIterationStatus`" after the `LoadAndRunAction`.
add it to terms of the report status for example "`If Reporter.CurrentActionIterationStatus = 1 Then ExitAction`"

`LoadAndRunAction` example:

```
LoadAndRunAction "{path to the tests}","{action name}",rngAll,DataTable("{Value}")
If Reporter.CurrentActionIterationStatus = 1 Then ExitAction
```

see also https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/23.4/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/OV_Supp_Util/Utility_Reporter.htm

Comment: Available only in newer UFT releases, fyi

Answer (score 0):

**Not directly.**

A similar idea would be to ask for the current run result status, see [How can I get the run result status according to the current report node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723774/how-can-i-get-the-run-result-status-according-to-the-current-report-node), but that is currently unsolved.

**You can, however, call your actions, and consume there return value**, like this:

```
ActionSucceeded=RunAction ("myTest [Action2]", oneIteration)
If not ActionSucceeded then
    ' The Action2 call signalled "failure" (false)
End If
```

**This implies that `Action2` must return such a result**, like in here:

```
ExitActionIteration (false)
```

**Beware**, however, of the fact that `RunAction` statements need to be inserted using QTP´s IDE (Insert/Call To Action...), resulting in a `RunAction` call without brackets. When editing this to the assignment form above (with brackets), make sure you get it right the first time before you save the test -- because **if you save a test containing a broken `RunAction` call, QTP disassociates the called test**, and the test will fail at runtime even if you edit the script back to correct syntax. This is due to metainfo that QTP saves invisibly in the script, and if you save an invalid action call, this metainfo is being discarded. (You can see when this happens because the action call will disappear from the test flow view.)

And: If you don´t store the `RunAction` result in a variable, but use it directly, like in

```
If not RunAction ("myTest [Action2]", oneIteration) then
    ' The Action2 call signalled "failure" (false)
End If
```

the same mess arises: QTP does not understand that this is a valid action call, and it won´t work even if you edit it into back into the original form.

**Except for the "beware" hint, the same holds true for `LoadAndRunAction`**, which calls an action at runtime. `LoadAndRunAction` can be called as a function, and if the called actions returns a value via `ExitActionIteration`, it returns that value.

**Yet another "beware" hint**: **`ExitActionIteration` really requires its arguments to be enclosed in brackets, even though it is a `Sub`** (or at least called as a `Sub`). I suspect this is because it is not a real `Sub` or `Function`, but a special statement "patched into" the MS VBScript engine in some exotic way.

Comment: Oh, I am using QTP, but I think it´s the same in UFT.