# UFT-API It is possible to get actual test/iteraction result on custom code

Tags: hp-uft

I need to generate a file with some values depending the test/iteration result (pass/fail).

It is possible to get actual test/iteraction result on custom code?

Comment: Google will help you with this.

Comment: I'm new with UFT-API and maybe I'm not searching correctly... but I didn't found anything that give me the currente status of a test on runtime.

Comment: Might ultimately duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723774/how-can-i-get-the-run-result-status-according-to-the-current-report-node